ZMPT101B AC mains voltage measurement circuit for industrial use
Taking from ZMPT101B modules which are popular among DIY folks, I've designed a circuit for AC voltage measurements using a microcontroller ADC (STM32L0).

The module doesn't do any rectification and simply offsets the lowered AC voltage to levels that the microcontroller can measure. I, on the other hand used a precision rectifier and a filter circuit to generate a DC level proportional to the input AC level. I wonder why the module didn't prefer this approach, the components that are required as pretty much the same. Are there any disadvantages to this approach?
Is this circuit safe and reliable to be used as a robust option for an industrial control panel? Anything that I missed in the design?
I had previously relied on a different circuit, but I've chosen not to use it because the isolation requires two different power supplies:

